# Which of the isomorphism theorems?

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with one and let $G=\{ g_{1}, g_{2}, ... g_{n}\}$ be a finite group.
Show that $$I = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}g_{i}\in R(G) \middle|\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}=0_{R}\right\}$$ 
is an ideal, and that $R(G)/I$ is isomorphic like a ring to $R$.

After that, show that $I$ is generated by $\{ {{g-e|g \in G}} \}$ , and, if $ G=\langle t\rangle$, then $I$ equal to $(t-e)$.

What of the isomorphism theorems should use in the part Of $R(G)/I$ isomosrphic to $R$?

I have the part of how that is an ideal, i have tried with the four isomorphism theorems, and I didn't solve it.

And, do you have a little hint for the second part (the second part of the second part)?

Comment: In English, words with an "eff" sound are usually written using "ph" instead of "f", unlike say Spanish. For example, "photo", "amphibian" or "morphism". In particular, "isomorphism".

Comment: But it is not phear, phor or phare but fea, for and fare...:)

Comment: Oh, common Pedro: I don't think even the purest of shakespearean  writers could find more than 2-3 persons in the whole world (up to and including Alabama) that would be able to distinguish that...it's not like "b" and "v" in many languages.

Comment: Common? I am so offended.

Comment: lol "isomosfirs" isn't even remotely close to phonetically correct

Comment: Oh, sorry: come on, Peter (?) ...:)

Comment: alternatively, those start with an $f$, unlike isomor$ph$ism

Answer (score 1):

Hint: define

$$\phi:RG\to R\;\;,\;\;\phi\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kg_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$

Show that $\;I=\ker\phi\;,\;\;\phi$ is onto, and then use the first isomorphism theorem

Comment: Dear @Julio : This map doesn't just come out of nowhere: it's what you get when the group homomorphism $G\to \{1\}$ is extended to all of $R[G]$ using the group-ring universal mapping property. (Just FYI, and good luck.)